# Trigonometry conversion rules, why this way?

Tags: trigonometry

We have domain $\,[0, 2\pi]\,$ and the following functions are given:
$$f(x)=\cos(2x) \text{ and } g(x)=\sin(x-\pi/3)$$Solve exactly: $\,f(x)=g(x)$

Why does one solve:
*(right way)*
$$\cos(2x)=\sin(x-\pi/3)\\\cos(2x)=\cos(\pi/2-(x-\pi/3))\\ \text{etc.}\ldots
$$
and not (which gives the wrong answer $\rightarrow a - k\,\, \times\,\, 2\pi \cdots$):
*(wrong way)*
$$\cos(2x)=\sin(x-\pi/3)\sin(\pi/2-(2x))=\sin(x-\pi/3)\\ \text{etc.}\ldots$$

---

**Right way fully worked out:**

$$\cos(2x) = \sin(x -\pi/3)\\
\cos(2x) = \cos(\pi/2 - (x -\pi/3))\\
\cos(2x) = \cos(\pi/2 - x + \pi/3)\\
\cos(2x) = \cos(5\pi/6 - x)\\
2x = (5\pi/6 - x) + k\,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
3x = 5\pi / 6 + k \,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
x = 5\pi /18 + k \,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\ 
or:\\
2x = - (5\pi/6 - x) + k\,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
x = -5\pi / 6 + k \,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
$$

---

**Wrong way fully worked out:**

$$\cos(2x) = \sin(x-\pi/3)\\
sin(\pi/2 - x)=\sin(x-\pi/3)\\
\pi/2-2x=(x-\pi/3)+k\,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
-3x = (-\pi/3 - \pi/2) + k\,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
-3x = -5\pi/6+ k\,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
x = 5\pi/18 -k \,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
or:\\
\pi/2-2x=\pi-(x-\pi/3) + k \,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\
\pi/2 - x = \pi - x + \pi/3 + k \,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\\ 
x= 4\pi/3-\pi/2 + k \,\, \times \,\, 2\pi\,\,\,\\\ \,\,\, =5\pi/6 - k \,\, \times \,\,2\pi
$$

---

On closer inspection of the worked out examples above you can clearly see that final answers of the wrong way are.. wrong. This because the answers we get aren't within the set domain.

Help is highly appreciated.

-Bowser

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with $a-k \times 2 \pi $

Comment: When you solve the right way you get: $a + k \,\,\,\times\,\,\, 2\pi$ which gives you all the solution you need. When you solve the wrong way you get $a - k \,\,\,\times\,\,\, 2\pi$. You see? because of the minus sign the answers you get are wrong.

Comment: We don't know what you mean by $a$, and we don't know what you mean by $k$. But if $k$ is supposed to run through the integers, then $a-2\pi k$ is exactly the same set of numbers as $a+2\pi k$, so both methods give you the same answer.

Comment: I'll write it out.

Comment: @gerryMyerson I've worked them out.

Comment: You have "worked them out", but the symbol $k$ has flown into your work from the blue, without any indication of what it means. My previous comment stands. Also, from $\cos v=\cos w$ (or $\sin v=\sin w$), you cannot draw the conclusion that $v$ is $w$ plus an integer multiple of $2\pi$. E.g., $\sin(\pi/6)=\sin(5\pi/6)$, but there is no integer $k$ such that $\pi/6=5\pi/6+2k\pi$. I think you have to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: $k$ is simply the next solution.. This is not something I'm making up. Maybe you've just been taught differently. I'll wait for someone else thanks anyway.

Comment: I have been taught that when you introduce a symbol, you tell people what that symbol stands for. I'm glad someone else came along to give you the answer on a silver platter, but, really, you would have done much better to think seriously about and engage with the comments I made.

Comment: Thanks for the rebuke. I'll try harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to transform the sine into cosine or conversely.

### First method

\begin{gather}
\cos2x=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right)
\\[6px]
\cos2x=\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}-x\right)
\\[6px]
2x=\frac{5\pi}{6}-x+2k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
2x=-\frac{5\pi}{6}+x+2k\pi
\\[6px]
x=\frac{5\pi}{18}+k\frac{2\pi}{3}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=-\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi
\end{gather}

### Second method

\begin{gather}
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x\right)=\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)
\\[6px]
\frac{\pi}{2}-2x=x-\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\frac{\pi}{2}-2x=\pi-x+\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi
\\[6px]
x=\frac{5\pi}{18}-k\frac{2\pi}{3}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=-\frac{5\pi}{6}-2k\pi
\end{gather}

### What's happening?

Nothing strange. In the solutions above, $k$ denotes an arbitrary integer: for *any* choice of the integer $k$, you get a solution. So writing $-k$ or $+k$ is irrelevant: the solution for $k=1$ in the first set (on the left side) appears in the solutions of the second set (left side) for $k=-1$.

The two forms give the *same* solutions.

If you want to find the solutions in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ you can do as follows, for the first method:
$$
0\le\frac{5\pi}{18}+k\frac{2\pi}{3}<2\pi
\iff
0\le5+12k<36
\iff
-5\le12k<31
$$
that gives $k=0,1,2$. Also
$$
0\le-\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi<2\pi
\iff
0\le-5+12k<12
\iff
5\le12k<17
$$
that gives $k=1$. So you have four solutions.

The same procedure in the second method would give $k=0,-1,-2$ in one case and $k=-1$ in the other.

Comment: Thank you so much! One glance at your answer and I understood.